# How to use the spark stats?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, statistics, apache-spark-dataset, quantile

I'm using spark-sql-2.4.1v, and I'm trying to do find quantiles i.e. percentile 0, percentile 25, etc, on each column of my given data.

As I am doing multiple percentiles, how to retrieve each calculated percentile from the results?

Here an example, having data as show below:

```
+----+---------+-------------+----------+-----------+
|  id|     date|total_revenue|con_dist_1| con_dist_2|
+----+---------+-------------+----------+-----------+
|3310|1/15/2018|  0.010680705|         6|0.019875458|
|3310|1/15/2018|  0.006628853|         4|0.816039063|
|3310|1/15/2018|   0.01378215|         4|0.082049528|
|3310|1/15/2018|  0.010680705|         6|0.019875458|
|3310|1/15/2018|  0.006628853|         4|0.816039063|
|3310|1/15/2018|   0.01378215|         4|0.082049528|
|3310|1/15/2018|  0.010680705|         6|0.019875458|
|3310|1/15/2018|  0.010680705|         6|0.019875458|
|3310|1/15/2018|  0.014933087|         5|0.034681906|
|3310|1/15/2018|  0.014448282|         3|0.082049528|
+----+---------+-------------+----------+-----------+
```

I need to calculate percentile 0, percentile25 etc, on "con_dist_1", "con_dist_2", etc.

I am doing the below for percentile 50:

```
val col_list = Array("con_dist_1","con_dist_2")
val median_col_list = partitioned_data.stat.approxQuantile(col_list, Array(0.5),0.0)
println(median_col_list)
```

It's giving this result:

```
median_col_list: Array[Array[Double]] = Array(Array(4.0), Array(0.034681906))
```

How to map the results? Is there any way which result is belongs to which column? Please suggest any better for the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate multiple percentiles at the same time, you can simple add them to the array you input to `approxQuantile`. For example, for 0, 25, 50, 75 and 100 you would do it as follows:

```scala
val col_list = Array("con_dist_1", "con_dist_2")
val percentiles = Array(0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0)
val median_col_list = partitioned_data.stat.approxQuantile(col_list, percentiles, 0.0)
```

The result will now be an array of arrays with all the percentiles.

To know which column the percentiles correspond to is simple, it depends on the order of the `col_list`. So in this case, `median_col_list(0)` corresponds to "con_dist_1" and `median_col_list(1)` to "con_dist_1". Following the same analogy, e.g. `median_col_list(1)(2)` would correspond to the 50 percentile for the "con_dist_1" column.